# "CreateProcess error=216" trying to run AutoIt script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am trying to upload an image to my website. I start with clicking the upload button. Then use AutoIt to fill the path of image in Windows dialog.

AutoIt script:

```
WinWait("Open","",10)
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

This works when I compile and run it by passing one argument. This was also working previously with my code. But it has stopped working:

> Cannot run program "Path to EXE": CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

In my Selenium code I am getting this error on `Runtime.getRuntime()`:

```
headShotButton.click();
URL resource = Main.class.getResource("/UploadControlScript.exe");
String absolutePath = "";
try {
    absolutePath = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toString();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Assert.fail("unable to get the Upload control script used (AUTOIT)" + e.getMessage().toString());
}
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(absolutePath + " " + uploadObj.ImageUploadPath);
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
int retCode = 0;
while (retCode != -1) {
        retCode = is.read();
}
```

I tried:

1. Setup Java compiler to JDK 1.8 (latest).
2. Add environment variable "JAVA_HOME" and set its directory to JDK 1.8 folder.